# How automatically fix html5 validation warnings?

Tags: css, html, web, automation, validation

I commonly write a lot html code and when I write I try to follow [the specification](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Specifications) for a valid and semantic web, normally following the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). For validate the HTML code I use the [official W3C Markup validator service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Also, I have to modify another HTML code from other coworkers, collaborators or even contribute in another external projects.

In my code normally I have a lot errors, but it is more heavy when you have to rewrite the code from others. Also this is a manual operation that cost a lot time only for get "green" status in a validator.

Some changes seems easy like a missing "/" in a `<img>` tag or a missing title or alt attribute are very frequent. I would know if there are some program or way of automatize certain changes for perform this changes (and don't reinvent the wheel) as a batch and avoid manual time cost with modifications. I mean, not only a check syntax validator (I think that IDEs like Eclipse do exactly that), I am searching more a writing analysis tool that modify the code warnings and fix too, not only warning you about them.

Comment: `automatize certain changes for perform this changes` no, simply because these are human errors. If you decide to nest tags, the validator has no way of knowing what order they should be in. True, there could be something like HTML Tidy to remove unexpected content, but that in turn might brick your code, causing more issues than it fixed.

Comment: Yep, I am aware, but for simply changes or at least a easy tool like pep8 that warns you, but you can automatize some type of warnings for fix (for example see https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8)

Comment: Why do you spend time to get “green” status from an experimental checker that checks against some unspecified work-in-progress? (They don’t say *which* HTML5 they check against.) Moreover, the question has some false premises; e.g., HTML5 does *not* require `/` in `img` except in XHTML syntax, and a `title` attribute is never required.

Comment: Because "green" status let you make a litte difference without others. Demostrate your knowlegde and respect about standars and best practices. HTML5 is currently experimental, but it evolves quickly and honestly it offers the best features than others.

Answer (score 1):

There's no machine or algorithm that can decide if a missing `alt` attribute needs to remain empty (`alt=""` because it's a decorative image) or what text should be put as a value.
You need to analyse many bits of context, know which information is being sent to users and how it'll have to be coded in this particular context.
From WebAIM :
[Creating Accessible Images - Creating Effective Alternative (alt)Text](http://webaim.org/techniques/images/alt_text)
[Appropriate Use of Alternative Text](http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/)

---

But to detect that `img` is lacking `alt` attribute is a job where computers are very useful and reliable (it's so tedious and easy to implement). Can be done with:

- extensions like Web Developer Toolbar,
- services like http://tanaguru.com ,
  "diagnostic" user stylesheets (something like `img:not([alt]) { border: 5px solid red }`
- regular expression in whatever language or text editor with [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

Getting rid of `/` is as simple as replacing `/>` by `>` (is it an error in HTML5?)

---

Why would you've to rewrite HTML code written from your colleagues?

- Train them to know what is a correct code and what is an error and to be careful when they're coding...
- They shouldn't commit code that results in HTML validation errors.
- Create and maintain [front-end developer’s style guide](http://24ways.org/2011/front-end-style-guides/)

Comment: I am not asking by fill automatically alt atribbutes. Instead detect when missing and suggest to add (empty) or manually adding a new alt text. I like this answer, but it is not the type of answer that I am expecting or solve really the problem.